# Render multiple components with f:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, commandbutton

The wrong codes are:

```
<h:form id="search_form">
<h:commandButton class="button" value="View" action="#{InfoBean.search}">
    <f:ajax execute="search_form" render="linear1"></f:ajax>
    <f:ajax execute="search_form" render="linear2"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
<p:lineChart id="linear1" value="#{InfoBean.linearModel1}" legendPosition="e"/>
<p:lineChart id="linear2" value="#{InfoBean.linearModel2}" legendPosition="e"/>
</h:form>
```

What I want to do is when I click on the `commandButton`, I want to refresh those two charts. But now I used two `<ajax>` tags, of which the second doesn't work.

So how can I use ajax to render two charts?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can render multiple components with single `f:ajax`. Just make sure all individual components you want to update have an `id`. In your sample it would be something like:

```
<f:ajax execute="search_form" render="linear1 linear2"/>
```

Where the IDs need to be separated by just whitespace like `linear1 linear2` and not commaseparated like `linear1, linear2` (that works only in `p:ajax`).

**See also:**

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces)
- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)

Comment: I wonder if there is a solution to render multiple dynamic components which will be created during run time

Comment: @electricalbah f:ajax reloads the elements from server. if by "runtime" you mean created via JS independent from the server then it's not possible to update them like this.

Answer (score 0):

For a4j jsf use ',':
`<a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="parent,child1,child2" />`