# Updating multiple components via <f:ajax render="foo,bar"> not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, rendering

Well, I have a delete button and when this button is clicked the item is removed from collection and the form should be clean.

So, this is my button:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="divTeste">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..."
                style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                <h:commandLink actionListener="#{cursoMB.deletarTeste()}"
                    styleClass="btn btn-default">
                    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="divTeste, divTestes" />
                    <i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></i>
                </h:commandLink>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Descrição</label>
                <h:inputText value="#{cursoMB.teste.descricao}"
                    disabled="#{cursoMB.teste == null}" styleClass="form-control" />
            </div>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

THis is the action in ManagedBean:

```
public void deletarTeste(){
        if (teste != null){
            bean.getTestes().remove(teste);
            teste = null;
            addInfoMessage("Teste deletado com sucesso");
        }else{
            addErrorMessage("Selecione um teste antes de deletar");
        }
    }
```

The XHTML uses the variable `teste`, when I call `deletarTeste()` method this variable is updated to NULL, and I hope that "form-group" be clean, but nothing happens.

**IMportant Note:**

If I use just 1 `id` to render, like this:

```
<f:ajax execute="@this" render="divTeste" />
```

Instead of:

```
<f:ajax execute="@this" render="divTeste, divTestes" />
```

Everything works, but I need update the 2 components.

Comment: you need to separete your ids with space and not "," like that: `render="divTeste divTestes"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render multiple components with f:ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597542/render-multiple-components-with-fajax)