# update a bean property from the same jsf

Tags: jsf

i want update a bean property from the same jsf wo contains this bean property by getting the new value from a method inside this bean.

here is the jsf sample :

```
<h3>JSF Login Logout</h3>
    <h:outputText value="Username" />
    <h:inputText id="username" value="#{login.user}"></h:inputText>
<h:outputText value="Password" />
    <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{login.pwd}"></h:inputSecret>
    <h:message for="password"></h:message>
    <br /><br />

    <h:commandButton action="#{login.validateUsernamePassword}"
        value="Login"></h:commandButton>
```

here is the bean method :

```
//validate login
public String validateUsernamePassword() {
...
    this.user = "admin";
...

}
```

i want return back to the same jsf and fill user field by the new value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stay on the same page then you don't have to return `String`, just create `void` method. If you want to update fields after form submit you can do it in JSF component by ajax with `render` attribute and specify these fields with ID or by selectors like `@form`:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{login.validateUsernamePassword}" value="Login">
    <f:ajax execute="formId" render="username otherComponentId"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

or update from backing bean:

```
public String validateUsernamePassword() {
...
    this.user = "admin";
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("formId:username"); //PrimeFaces solution since you have PrimeFaces tag on your question
...

}
```

Better option is to use `render` attribute and probably you would like to also update `h:message` for any occurred errors (give it ID and update it in `render`).

- [Difference between returning null and "" from a JSF action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744162/difference-between-returning-null-and-from-a-jsf-action)
- [Can I update a JSF component from a JSF backing bean method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365094/can-i-update-a-jsf-component-from-a-jsf-backing-bean-method)
- [Render multiple components with f:ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597542/render-multiple-components-with-fajax)