# How to properly update (render) <h:selectManyListbox.../>?

Tags: ajax, jsf, commandlink

What is wrong whit this code? I can not update the idOfForm (selectManyListbox )?

```
<h:form id="idOfForm">    
    <h:selectManyListbox id="userListId" size="10" value="#{userBean.selectedAvailableUsers}">
                                                    <f:selectItems 
                                                        value="#{userBean.availableUsers}" /> 
                                                    <f:converter converterId="userConverter" /> 
                                                </h:selectManyListbox> 
    </h:form>



        <h:commandLink value="#{userBean.id}"
                                    action="#{userBean.update()}">
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                        target="#{userBean.selectedUser}" value="#{userBean}" />
                                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":idOfForm" />
                                </h:commandLink>
```

Comment: I cannot use update because commandLink does not have update as a attribute?

Comment: try adding `ajax = false` to the `<h:commandLink value="#{item.user}" ....` tag

Comment: I know try my solution first after that if it's not working try to replace your rendred with `rendred = "detailData  editUserForm"`

Comment: ajax is not supported by <h:commandLink. It is wrong without " : " .

Comment: did you try to update from the `managedBean` ?!? @geek_winner

Comment: Yes I did and it does not work. But it works without :editUserForm or: <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":detailData" /> (just for the first form)

Comment: try to replace the execut="@form" with execut="this"

Comment: No, this is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute an update from your managedBean like this

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form1");
```

also read this question [Render multiple components with f:ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597542/render-multiple-components-with-fajax) it's look like a similar question.

Try it