# JSF Component addressing

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to understand whats different between this addressing pattern in jsf .
for example I have this xhtml structure :

```
<h:panelGroup id="parent">
    <h:panelGroup id="child">
        <!-- 
          and some other components .
        -->
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

What is diff between this updates ?

```
   update="parent child"    
   update="parent:child"      
   update="parent,child"
```

Comment: Although there is no real ajax updating here, the use of `update` instead of `render` indicates the use of PrimeFaces, correct?

Comment: Everything you need to know is in the duplicate. Part of which is a little more clearly stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597542/render-multiple-components-with-fajax